# Grails: How to create formula on an embedded class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When I create a general class to embed it to other class, I want to add a transient property which is defined by a formula, but I do not how to implement this. Here is my source code:

```
//Embedded
class LocationInfo {
    Long country, state, city
    String address, fullAddress

    static constraints = {
        country nullable: true
        state nullable: true
        city nullable: true
        address nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        country column: 'l_country'
        state column: 'l_state'
        city column: 'l_city'
        address column: 'l_address'
        fullAddress formula: "SELECT (l_address || ', ' || city.name) FROM system_location city  WHERE city.id = l_city"
    }

    static transients = ['fullAddress']
}  

class SystemLocation {
    String name
    Long parentLocationId
    String level

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false, maxSize: 100
        parentLocationId nullable: true
        level inList: ['country', 'state', 'city']
    }

    static mapping = { version false }
}  

//Host
class User {
    String email
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Team team
    UserLevel userLevel
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired = false
    boolean accountLocked = false
    boolean passwordExpired = false
    boolean teamLeader = false

    LocationInfo locationInfo
    AuditingInfo auditingInfo

    static embedded = ['locationInfo', 'auditingInfo']

    transient springSecurityService
    static constraints = {
        email blank: false, unique: true, maxSize: 200
        password blank: false, maxSize: 200
        firstName blank: false
        lastName blank: false
        team nullable: true
        teamLeader nullable: true
        locationInfo nullable: true
        auditingInfo nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        team column: "team_id"
        userLevel column: "user_level_id"
    }  
}
```

The `LocationInfo` is embedded to `User` class, nhưng when I get a specific user by ID and check the value in `user.locationInfo.fullAddress`, it is always NULL; and the generated SQL does not contains the "SELECT (l_address || ', ' || city.name)..." statement.
I do not know how to use a formula in an embedded class.

Could you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Grails manual there is no such thing like `formula` in the mapping settings.

I'd solve this by simply declaring a getter method on your domain class:

```
class LocationInfo {
    Long country, state, 
    SystemLocation city
    String address    // n.b. no longAddress here

    static constraints = {
        country nullable: true
        state nullable: true
        city nullable: true
        address nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        country column: 'l_country'
        state column: 'l_state'
        address column: 'l_address'
    }

    static transients = ['fullAddress']

    String getFullAddress() {
       "$address $city.name"
    }
}
```

N.B. that city is now a reference to another domain class. In your draft this is just an id which makes your domain model hard to navigate.

Comment: Thank you for your response Stefan. But the "formula" attribute is actually supported by Grails, and I used to apply it when I work with Grails 1.3.7. My problem is I do not know how to make it work in an embeddded class, because it still works well with a particular domain class.

Comment: The "formula" option does exist, it's explained in the section named ["derived properties"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I think you can't do this that way.

When you define formula for some derived property, you have to put SQL with names of columns you know. But when this class is used in embedded property column names of that embedded object are changed.

In your case table User has columns location_info_l_city, location_info_l_address. But in formula you used names like l_city, l_address... There is no such column in table User.

I resolved the problem by adding derived property for embedded object's owner.
In your case I would add to class User mapping:

```
class User {
   //...
   String fullAddress
   //...
   static mapping = {
       //...
       fullAddress formula: "SELECT (location_info_l_address || ', ' || city.name) FROM system_location city  WHERE city.id = location_info_l_city"
   }
}
```

Now, you can use column User.fullAddress also in HQL queries.